# htaccess rewrite rule not returning URL parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess mod rewrite rule. It does not return the query string.

What is missing to return the query string?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

URL string:

```
http://cdn.test.dev/file/1/1/1/assets/dgdsfg.jpg?some=param
```

Result:

```
1/1/1/assets/dgdsfg.jpg
```

Comment: Try to add `[QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: What is the aim? To append the query string to the result?

Comment: Ah, it is working.

Comment: Great... Let me post that as an answer and you can approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `[QSA,NC,L]` instead of `[NC,L]`